# Combine overloading for different types of Dictionary into one function

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need a helper function to convert string like `"1=alice;2=bob;3=charlie"` into a `Dictionary<int, string>`, and string like `"1=true;2=false;3=true"` into a `Dictionary<int, bool>`, and etc.

To do this, I wrote a lot of helper functions that are basically copy and pasted of each other:

```
    private static void load(Dictionary<int, string> dict, string s)
    {
        dict.Clear();
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            if (item.Contains("="))
            {
                string[] kv = item.Split('=');
                dict[int.Parse(kv[0])] = kv[1];
            }
        }
    }

    private static void load(Dictionary<int, bool> dict, string s)
    {
        dict.Clear();
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            if (item.Contains("="))
            {
                string[] kv = item.Split('=');
                dict[int.Parse(kv[0])] = bool.Parse(kv[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void load(Dictionary<int, int> dict, string s)
    {
        dict.Clear();
        string[] items = s.Split(';');
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            if (item.Contains("="))
            {
                string[] kv = item.Split('=');
                dict[int.Parse(kv[0])] = int.Parse(kv[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are more, on other data types such as `long`, `DateTime`, and etc.

Is there a way to have just one helper function? I tried `Dictionary<object, object>` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it generic and use [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx), which will try to parse any string input to the output type:

```
private static void load<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dict, string s)
{
    dict.Clear();
    string[] items = s.Split(';');
    foreach (string item in items)
    {
        if (item.Contains("="))
        {
            string[] kv = item.Split('=');
            dict[int.Parse(kv[0])] = (T)Convert.ChangeType(kv[1], typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should have a generic method instead. Personally I'd make it return a new dictionary rather than clearing an existing one, mind you... and use LINQ to implement it:

```
private static Dictionary<int, T> Load<T>(string text, Func<string, T> parser)
{
    return s.Split(';')
            .Where(item => item.Contains("="))
            .Select(item => item.Split('=', 2))
            .ToDictionary(pair => int.Parse(pair[0]), pair => parser(pair[1]));
}
```

Then call it with:

```
Dictionary<int, int> foo = Load(text, int.Parse);
Dictionary<int, bool> bar = Load(text, bool.Parse);
Dictionary<int, string> baz = Load(text, x => x);
```